# Python, PyInstaller - delete folder containing exe

Tags: python, windows, exe, pyinstaller

To uninstall a program that has been built with pyInstaller I need to delete the folder containing the executable. How could I go about that without leaving any files after the uninstallation?
It only has to work on Windows (> Server 2012)